# nuget add does not work in msbuild exec command

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package

I am trying to automate process Build -> Pack -> Add for nuget package in VS2022. I have created SDK type project and using default settings to create nuget package. After executing Pack Command in Release mode, I have the following output in /bin/Release/ folder:

```
net8.0/    contains library files
my-package.nupkg
```

So far so good. Now I would like to execute nuget add command automatically after the Pack command completed, and publish the nuget package to my local repository. When I start power shell in the folder where csproj file is, and execute the following command:

```
nuget add bin/Release/my-package.0.0.1.nupkg -Source 'c:\Users\MyUser\OneDrive\nuget\packages\'
```

the command completes successfully, and I can see and use the package from other solutions.

However, if I try to automate this, it does not work. In csproj file:

```
<Target Name="AddPackage" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <Message Text="Adding nuget file to local repository..." Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="nuget add bin/Release/$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg -Source 'c:\Users\MyUser\OneDrive\nuget\packages\'" />
</Target>
```

Output window shows error:

```
1>Adding nuget file to local repository...
1>The given path's format is not supported.
error MSB3073: The command "nuget add bin/Release/my-package.0.0.1.nupkg -Source 'c:\Users\MyUser\OneDrive\nuget\packages\'" exited with code 1.
```

I also tried without relative path:

```
Command="nuget add $(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg -Source ....
Command="nuget add my-package.0.0.1.nupkg -Source ....
```

and copied manually the nupkg file in csproj folder, and same error.

Anyone knows why is it working from command line and not from VS, and how can I automate this task from VS Build/Pack process?

Comment: This is a question related to XML syntax confliction, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your issue:

[image]

I think you need something like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>ClassLibrary1</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.0</PackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="AddPackage" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <Message Text="Adding nuget file to local repository..." Importance="high" />
  <!--<Exec Command="nuget add bin/Release/$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg -Source 'c:\Users\MyUser\OneDrive\nuget\packages\'" />-->
  <Exec Command="nuget add &quot;$(ProjectDir)bin\Release\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg&quot; -Source &quot;C:\Path\To\Your\NuGet\Package\Source&quot;" />
</Target>
</Project>
```

And you can see that it success on my side:

[image]

The crucial thing is the file is XML format.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that if I removed '' completely from source path., it works. However, that will work only for paths that do not have spaces in it. Your solution is spot on.